# Inserting data from two tables which may have matching columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 3 Tables: `Tbl1`, `Tbl2` and `Tbl3`.

Tbl3 has a structure such that most Columns in Tbl3 are present in `Tbl2 + Tbl1`.

I don't know which columns match and which ones don't.

I want to insert data from `Tbl1` and `Tbl2` to `Tbl3`.

Is there a way to determine Column names that match Tbl3 and then insert data from Tbl1 and Tbl2?

Possible structure of tables is like:

> Tbl1 ---> Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |.... Column78
>
> Tbl2 ---> Column79 | Column80 | Column81 |.... Column 100
>
> Tbl3 ---> Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |.... Column100 | Column101 |
>   Column102... Column 120

Answer (score 1):

You can get the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns`.  You then have to manually create the query yourself:

```
select tbl3.table_name,
       (case when ct1.TABLE_NAME is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end) as InTbl1,
       (case when ct2.TABLE_NAME is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end) as InTbl2
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns ct3 left outer join
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns ct1
     on ct1.COLUMN_NAME = ct3.COLUMN_NAME and
        ct1.TABLE_NAME = 'tbl1' left outer join
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns ct2
     on ct2.COLUMN_NAME = ct3.COLUMN_NAME and
        ct2.TABLE_NAME = 'tbl2' left outer join
where ct3.TABLE_NAME = 'tbl3';
```

With this information you can then construct the query that you want.